# Initialization of a member variable tuple

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype

I have the following code:

```
struct A
{
    const string name;

    A(string name) :name(name) {}
};

struct Parent 
{
public:
    const decltype(make_tuple(A("AA"))) children{ make_tuple(A("AA")) };

    Parent()
    {

    }

};
```

Is it possible to avoid typing A("AA") twice?

Like when you use the auto keyword- but working.

Comment: `std::tuple<A> children{ A("AA") };`? Not sure what you're trying to do though.

Comment: Placeholder types aren't allowed for NSDMIs.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to copy paste the type.I would like to only having to tell the compiler once what type children is.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do besides a macro for data members.

Comment: Ohh- yes, of course- I should have mentioned I would like to avoid macros :)

Comment: Certainly. Maybe a proposal for this will come along. Interestingly, `BOOST_AUTO` should still work in this context, but of course it's still a macro (albeit a more widely-known one) and much more limited.

Comment: You could also do `tuple<A> children{ {"AA"} }` not that it's any more readable.

Comment: perhaps I could use something from http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/ but I think the standard will be changed so it will become impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move `A("AA")` or even better `make_tuple(A("AA"))` into its own function:

```
namespace {
    auto make_children() { return make_tuple(A("AA")); }
}

struct Parent 
{    
public:
    const decltype(make_children()) children{ make_children() };

    Parent()
    {

    }

};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd974141eb6025e8)

That way you only need to repeat the name of the helper function twice. Depending on the size/complexity of the expression in your real code, that might be a win.